# What is the sensitivity / specificity of a symptom?

Tags: statistics, influenza

I know the two terms in the context of a classification problem:

A classification algorithms sensitivity/specificity is defined as

```
sensitivity = TP / (TP + FN)
specificity = TN / (TN + FP)
```

I like the comparison with a fire alarm:

- If the **sensitivity** is high, that means it actually starts ringing when there is a fire. It could still be that FP is high, meaning it just rings all the time.
- If the **specificity** is high, it means it does not ring when there is no fire. It could still be that FN is high which means it does not ring when there is a fire.

Now I found [a table for Influenza symptoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influenza#Signs_and_symptoms) and I'm a bit confused what it means in this context. Does it essentially define each isolated symptom as a classification algorithm, e.g. for fever:

- I get a patient who has Influenza. I only check for fever. If the patient has fever, I conclude that he has Influenza. I'm right in 68–86% of the cases. (For simplicity, assume 77%)
- I get a patient and and apply my "fever => Influenza" logic. In 25–73% of the cases I correctly say that they don't have fever (for simplicity, assume 49%).

So essentially the number come from filling this table:

```
|                         | Correct Pred. (True) | Wrong Prediction (False) |
| ----------------------- | -------------------- | ------------------------ |
| Has Fever (Positive)    |                      |                          |
| Has no Fever (Negative) |                      |                          |
```

**Specificity**: Hence, if I divide the number of people without fever and who also don't have influenza by the number of all people without influenza, it should be 49%? Or is it all people who visit the doctor? All people who feel sick? All people who think they have Influenza?

**Sensitivity**: I divide the number of people who have fever and influenza by the number of people with Influenza. Same question here: If people are asymptomatic, they probably don't go to the doctor. If there is no check if they had influenza, how can one have `FN`?

Did I get something completely wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to ask (in the title Q) about S&S of  **symptom** or did you mean **test**, as in a diagnostic test?

Comment: In your algorithm, does "FP" represent false-positive results, while "FN" represents false-negatives results (of a test).

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Medical_examples) says:

> In medical diagnosis, test **sensitivity is the ability of a test to
>   correctly identify those with the disease** (true positive rate),
>   whereas test **specificity is the ability of the test to correctly
>   identify those without the disease** (true negative rate). If 100
>   patients known to have a disease were tested, and 43 test positive,
>   then the test has 43% sensitivity. If 100 with no disease are tested
>   and 96 return a negative result, then the test has 96% specificity.
>   Sensitivity and specificity are prevalence-independent test
>   characteristics, as their values are intrinsic to the test and do not
>   depend on the disease prevalence in the population of interest.[10]
>   Positive and negative predictive values, but not sensitivity or
>   specificity, are values influenced by the prevalence of disease in the
>   population that is being tested. These concepts are illustrated
>   graphically in this applet Bayesian clinical diagnostic model which
>   show the positive and negative predictive values as a function of the
>   prevalence, the sensitivity and specificity.

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity it says:

> **Sensitivity** (also called the true positive rate, the recall, or
>   **probability of detection**[1] in some fields) measures the proportion of
>   actual positives that are correctly identified as such (e.g., the
>   percentage of sick people who are correctly identified as having the
>   condition).

I. e. sensitivity refers to the proportion of people with disease who have a positive test result.

> **Specificity** (also called the true negative rate) measures
>   the proportion of **actual negatives that are correctly identified as
>   such** (e.g., the percentage of healthy people who are correctly
>   identified as not having the condition).

I. e. specificity refers to the proportion of people without disease who have a negative test result.

In summary:

- Sensitivity is the proportion of patients with the disease who have
  the symptom.
- Specificity is the proportion of patients without the
  disease who do not have the symptom.

Comment: Not diagnosis, disease. Diagnosis is a social construction. Some people with a diagnosis don’t have the diagnosed disease; having a disease without it being diagnosed is common.

Comment: True, thanks for the correction.